# CARLA Quick-start Crashing with Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: mutex, ros2, carla

Using Carla quick-start build, and just trying to launch CARLA
Installed CARLA quickstart according to the docs for 0.9.12, and facing a core dump issue.. unclear why?

**CARLA version 0.9.12**

**About my Linux Machine**

> Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04 KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8 KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0 Qt Version:
> 5.12.8 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-56-generic OS Type: 64-bit Processors: 16 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz Memory: 31.1 GiB of RAM

**My Graphics/GPU**

```
user@my-machine:lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"

0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 65f1
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3080 Mobile / Max-Q 8GB/16GB] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device 65f1
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

**ERROR & CRASH**

```
user@my-machine:/opt/carla-simulator$ ./CarlaUE4.sh
   
 4.26.2-0+++UE4+Release-4.26 522 0
    Disabling core dumps.
    ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.
    X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
      Major opcode of failed request:  149 ()
      Minor opcode of failed request:  4
      Serial number of failed request:  285
      Current serial number in output stream:  295
    terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error: mutex lock failed: Invalid argument
    Signal 6 caught.
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
export VK_ICD_FILENAMES="/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json"  && ./CarlaUE4.sh
```

on some systems also
`./CarlaUE4.sh -opengl`
works

see https://github.com/carla-simulator/carla/issues/2232